# Sql code when using in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

> While going through some of your data, you see that there are some outliers in shipdate that have badly affected your results.  Use the following as the basis for your query but strip off all shipdates less than 0 or greater than 365 days difference from the order date.

Here is the SQL I have written up so far. What am I missing?

```
SELECT ol.shipdate - o.orderdate as day, COUNT(*) as numol
FROM dw.orders o JOIN dw.orderline ol ON o.orderid = ol.orderid
group by (ol.shipdate - o.orderdate)
ORDER BY 1;
```

This problem is out of a book that I'm working on by myself.

Comment: you haven't specified a `WHERE` criteria

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a `WHERE` clause to filter the results.  For example:

```
SELECT ol.shipdate - o.orderdate as day, COUNT(*) as numol
FROM dw.orders o JOIN dw.orderline ol ON o.orderid = ol.orderid
WHERE (ol.shipdate - o.orderdate) BETWEEN 0 AND 365
GROUP BY (ol.shipdate - o.orderdate)
ORDER BY 1;
```

However, instead of repeating `(ol.shipdate - o.orderdate)` many times, you may opt to put it in a subquery like this:

```
SELECT day, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT (ol.shipdate - o.orderdate) AS day
    FROM dw.orders o
    JOIN dw.orderline ol
    ON o.orderid = ol.orderid
)
WHERE day BETWEEN 0 AND 365
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day;
```

Note: here's the documentation on the [BETWEEN condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147).  It's the same as - in our case - doing something like `(day >= 0 AND day <= 365)`.

Comment: that where clause doesn't work in the sql command in oracle @Mr.Llama

Comment: @mike: The `where` clause is just located in the wrong place in this answer. It should be before the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Allan I had WHERE (ol.shipdate - o.orderdate) BETWEEN 0 AND 365 on top of the GROUP BY and still didn't work says it not properly ended

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider how you simply translate the english into a "where" clause

```
 Where (ol.shipdate - o.orderdate) > 0 
   and (ol.shipdate - o.orderdate) < 366
```